# Jquery clone name attribute increase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm looking to clone addDriverContent (working fine) and increment the numbers for the name attribute on name="description" to name="description2", name="description3" on the clones

Also if anyone know how to also clone the add button so it works as it should on the clones would be extra points :) Some fiddles would be awesome :)

```
<div id="addDriverContent" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="description" class="form-label font-weight-bold">Item Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter the items description"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button" id="clone_button">Add another item</button>
                            
<div id="clone_wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($) {

        var max_fields        = 4; 
        // origin selector would select all the first div ancestors.
        var $content          = $("#addDriverContent > .content");     
        var $clone_wrapper    = $("#clone_wrapper") ;
        var $add_button       = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        

        $add_button.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var counter = 0;
            // jquery object is array liked object. Length mean how many elements is selected.
            if ( $clone_wrapper.children(".content").length < max_fields ) 
            
            $content.clone().appendTo($clone_wrapper);
        });
        
        $clone_wrapper.on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        
            // this would be more specific.
            $(this).parent(".content").remove(); 
        })
        
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you don't do this. Creating dynamic incremental attributes is a code smell, which creates more complex code than is required. The better approach would be to create all your `input` elements with the same name. That way they will be sent to the server-side code as an array which you can loop through there.

Comment: The problem I have with looping post request data is the DB is setup like this

<tablename>
Id
description1
description2
description3
description4
description5

So can’t loop through this data in Django as it’s only sending the last value in the original/clones, there may or not be data in anything else but description1.  If this was in PHP I would be good to go.

Comment: In which case I'd suggest you improve your database design. Store each description as its own entity with a relationship to the original record id.

Comment: If it was my choice, this would be rebuilt from scratch but the powers that be don't want to, they just want the frontend to be dynamic vs five hard coded description boxes.

Comment: You cannot have duplicated id's. The cloned `<input>` is `#description`. You should remove that id or you can make a bigger mess and number each of the clones' ids as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have no idea what you intend to do with it, I will provide you with my dirty solution for it:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addDriverContent" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="description" class="form-label font-weight-bold">Item Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="description form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter the items description"/>
<input type="text" class="fname form-control" id="fname" name="fname"/>
                <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><button type="button" class="add_field_button" id="clone_button">Add another item</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button" id="clone_button">Add another item</button>
                            
<div id="clone_wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($) {
    
    

        var max_fields        = 4; 
        // origin selector would select all the first div ancestors.
        var $content          = $("#addDriverContent > .content");     
        var $clone_wrapper    = $("#clone_wrapper") ;
        var $add_button       = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        

        $(".add_field_button").click(function() {
            //e.preventDefault();
            //var counter = 0;
            // jquery object is array liked object. Length mean how many elements is selected.
            if ( $clone_wrapper.children(".content").length < max_fields ) {
            
            $content.clone().appendTo($clone_wrapper);
            //$add_button.clone().appendTo($clone_wrapper);// mine
            
            $(".description").each(function(index) { 
            $( this ).attr('name', 'description'+index)
            });
            
            $(".fname").each(function(index) { 
            $( this ).attr('name', 'fname'+index)
            });
          
         
            }

           
        });
        
        
                $(document).on('click', "#clone_wrapper .add_field_button", function () {
            $('#addDriverContent + .add_field_button').trigger('click');
})
          $(document).on('click', ".remove_field", function () {
            //e.preventDefault(); 
        
            // this would be more specific.
            $(this).closest(".content").remove(); 
        }); 
        
        
   
        
        
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: This sort of works apart from remove does not remove the but extra add button when removing a clone and if I add an extra input it will rename the name=fname to description+num -- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"/>

Comment: I do really not get the point of your remove click function. It is not even working for me. Clicking on the whole wrapper should remove one item? I neither understood the second part of the issue stated in this comment.

Comment: Simpley put, when I click on Add another item, this adds the div correctly, but if there is another form element  (<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"/>) along side the <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"/> the name="fname" gets changed to ame="description2" too. then on the next add it become 3 and 4 and so on.

What I want is for fname to be fname1 and description1 and then on add 2 and 2 and so on.

Comment: If I click on the remove button this removes the div but leaves a duplicated 'Add another item button', then further duplicates again and again the button. missed this bit of code out  <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a> is what removes the div.

Comment: I am not sure if I got it right but I just changed the code. Please check my edited answer

Comment: This is almost correct just need to support two inputs <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"/> and <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"/> so they both increment on the name by 1 (i.e fname1 and description1 then on click of add more fname2 and description2)

Comment: Okay, please check it again I fixed some stuff.

Comment: how would i go about have a version where description, and weight, length blah blah are on screen without having to press the add item button first, with then being able to add more items?

Comment: how would i go about have a version where description, and weight, length blah blah are on screen without having to press the add item button first, with then being able to add more items?